# Django No Reverse Match on Nginx Server

Tags: django, python-3.x, ubuntu, nginx, server

I am trying to build a simple blog application on an ubuntu droplet hosted on digital ocean.

I have the DJango app in mid development and I am getting a No reverse match for a view that existes

Here is the error:

```
'NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'post_detail' not found. 'post_detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.'
```

Here is my Url Patterns:

```
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
        url(r'^post/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
]
~
```

Here is My view

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})

def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})
~
```

Here is My nginx file:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /static/ {
    root /home/XXXX/Django;
}

location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/XXX/Django/BizBlog.sock;
}
}
```

Where is the error occurring? I can't figure this out, I have worked with Django before and know it has to do with the url searching for the string patterns in my view function and being unable to find it but the function is there. What is wrong?

Here is my main url.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include
from django.conf.urls import url

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

Comment: Please post your main `urls.py` as well. Are you using `namespace`s?

Comment: And why do you think this has to do with nginx? Does it work in development?

Comment: posted my main url.py, I will check if it works in dev.

Comment: Just checked Yes it works just as it should.

Comment: any thoughts on what might be causing the issue?

Comment: Any solution found for this error. I am able to run the code in django development server but it fails when i run it on nginx.

Answer (score 0):

Just stop the django development server process, restart the services waitress on windows/gunicorn on linux and nginx on windows/linux.